# Autocomplete from 10 000 items in .NET

Tags: .net

I've got an in memory collection of around 10K objects. I want to give users the ability to type part of the item name or description and display an autocomplete list. What is an efficient way to do it? I really need the fastest possible response time, users are very fast.

Thanks a lot,
Mary

Comment: What's the UI built with? Windows Forms, WPF, a web app from ASP.Net?

Comment: It's ASP MVC app, a web page will request on keypress JSONP from a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a .net specific answer, but the usual approach to this problem is to create an index and pre-compute your auto-complete lists which are stored in a hierarchical map-of-maps-of-maps-of...-of-maps-of-lists structure (see below). It's basically an implementation of a **trie**.

Basically, you have a hash map (REAL hash map, with O(1) implementation), with keys being possible substrings. For each key string "XYZ", it points to a map containing data for all objects containing "XYZ"; with keys "XYZA", "XYZB", ...etc... Then once you reach N characters (N maps deep), your last map value is a LIST of all actual objects from your collection which contain that N-character string.

Then you go over your collection, and for each object compute all possible substrings of length M through N (I assume you only want to autocomplete if >=M characters is typed; and too-long substrings are useless) and populate the maps.

The data structure is as follows:

```
TopMap => {
          'A' => Map_for_A
          'B' => Map_for_B
              ...
          }

Map_For_A => {
          'AA' => Map_for_AA
          'AB' => Map_for_AB
              ...
          }
Map_For_AB => {
          'ABC' => Map_for_ABC
          'ABD' => Map_for_ABD
              ...
          }
Map_For_ABD => {
          'ABDE' => List_For_ABDE
          'ABDX' => List_For_ABDX
          }
```

Answer (score 9):

Arrange your data as a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

[image: Trie]

Comment: Specifically, a suffix tree if full-text search is needed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Comment: http://www.techtalkz.com/c-c-sharp/161743-implementation-string-trie.html or http://www.kerrywong.com/2006/04/01/implementing-a-trie-in-c/

Comment: @Chris: From the word "autocomplete" in the title I had assumed that the user would always start typing at the beginning of the description. But that's good to know, I actually had no idea tries could also be used for full text search!

Answer (score 1):

10'000 objects really isn't much.

The below should suffice.

```
foreach(cItem Item in ItemList)
{
     if(regex.match(Item.Name, "expression"))
         //Add Item to autocomplete results;


         //Break if more than 10 matches

}



for(i = 0; i < 10 && i < autocomplete_results.Length; ++i)
{
          // display first 10 matches
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Trie data structure (or prefix tree) to hold the names of items. See this very detailed [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) on wikipedia that describes the principles of this data structres and provides some benchmark results.

Each node of the Trie can be implemented as a sorted list of characters corresponding to the N-th position in individual data strings, where N is the depth of the node. You can then use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) to perform data lookups efficiently.

To make it work in your case, just keep the last node corresponding to the previously entered prefix. When the user types the next letter, just search for the corresponding immediate child.

Everything within the respective subtree is a possible match and hence can be offered to the user. To make the autocomplete smarter, you could keep track of frequencies of individual data items and display the most frequent ones only.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to drop those values in a page say in a javascript variable (string array) using for example a literal control  and then use something like this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#Example

Comment: jQuery, for a question tagged `.NET`?

Comment: hummm...yeah? Why not? never used jquery with an ASP.NET project?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't want to give the user every possible choice- for example, if the list of items is a set of names, typing the letter "E" and getting every name with an E in it in the dropdown would be neither efficient or quick-performing for the user.  Have you considered only suggesting a result when the user has typed 3 (or more) characters?

If the set of items is static, this would (potentially) allow you you pre-calculate the set of items for every unique 3- or 4-character set, and store them in a dictionary of lists, something like:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Item>> itemsByKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which User Interface you are using. If you are using ASP.NET Web forms, you can use AutoComplete control from AjaxControlToolkit.

Here you can find a demonstration: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx